# openstack create new instance with static ip with ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, openstack, openstack-nova

tried to launch VM using Fixed IP While creating new Instances with Ansible Playbook without assigning/Associating floating IPs. below Playbook .. please correct me if it's working. Not able to execute the playbook.

```
---
- name: launch a compute instance with fixed IP
  hosts: Controllerha
  gather_facts: True
  tasks:
  - name: Creating port
    os_port:
      auth:
        auth_url: http://10.10.16.10:5000/v3/
        username: admin
        password: 2322342jkvfjlk
        project_name: admin
        project_domain_name: Default
        user_domain_name: Default
      state: present
      name: kub-mas-port1
      server: Kub-Master-1
      network: Test-VLAN
      fixed_ips:
        - ip_address: 10.200.18.18

  - name: Creating New Instance Kub VM
    os_server:
      auth:
        auth_url: http://10.10.16.10:5000/v3/
        username: Test-por
        password: Poreere1212
        project_name: test
        project_domain_name: Default
        user_domain_name: Default
      state: present
      name: Kub-Master-1
      flavor: 4V8R40G
      boot_volume: Kub-Master
      timeout: 200
      security_groups: default
      nics:
       - net-id: f7FFf-da22-4844-8c8b-0dfdfdfdde7d
       - port-name: kub-mas-port1
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run the playbook. Do you get an error message of some sort?

Comment: Here the link Error is getting 

[ https://pastebin.com/qMnZxF7g ] 

**TASK [Creating Kub VM] 
task path: /etc/ansible/kub-master.yaml:23
fatal: [10.200.6.3]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find port by port-name: kub-mas-port-1"} **

.. Port was created but it's not assigned to the VM. 
it's there anything that needs to add a timeout to create an instance then the port will be added into an instance? @larsks

Answer (score 0):

In Admin project accounts I can able to launch an instance with using the below playbook but not in other projects. There are privileges issues Somewhere in nova and Neutron roles.

Even I added a test-pro project as an admin role. That time I found an issue with neutron service not able to add a port to the instance while running the playbook. it Went to Error state. Then I realized the problem with roles and privileges. Tried with the Admin project it's successfully rolled my playbook without any issues. Here the final playbook.

```
---
- name: launch a compute instance
  hosts: Controller
  gather_facts: True
  tasks:
  - name: Creating port
    os_port:
      auth:
        auth_url: http://10.20.8.19:5000/v3/
        username: admin
        password: XXansereat1234???
        project_name: admin
        project_domain_name: Default
        user_domain_name: Default
      state: present
      name: kub-mas-port1
      device_owner: compute:compute-02.local
      network: Test-network
      fixed_ips:
        - ip_address: 10.200.18.18
    register: port_info

 

  - name: Creating Kub-Master VM
    os_server:
      auth:
        auth_url: http://10.20.8.19:5000/v3/
        username: admin
        password: XXansereat1234???
        project_name: admin
        project_domain_name: Default
        user_domain_name: Default
      state: present
      availability_zone: compute-02.local
      name: Kub-MasterNode
      flavor: 4V8R40G
      boot_volume: Kub-Master
      wait: yes
      nics:
       - "port-id={{ port_info.id }}"
```